# Namespaces in C# Same Project

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a static class like so:

```
namespace Engine.Configuration
{
    public static class Configuration
    {
        public static int i;
    }
}
```

In the same project, but a different namespace I have a class trying to access the static class variable:

```
namespace Engine.MainProgram
{
    public class MainProgram
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        public void LoadConfiguration()
        {
            x = Configuration.Configuration.i;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is just place a using statement in MainProgram like so:

```
using Engine.Configuration;
...
x = Configuration.i;
```

But when I try to visual studio always treats Configuration as a namespace instead of the static class. My question is why does this happen and how do I correct this?

Comment: One approach: `using Configuration = Engine.Configuration.Configuration; .. x = Configuration.i;`. Although I would recommend keeping namespace and type names unique.

Comment: your class name and namespace name are the same..This is ambiguous..You should avoid setting the same name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't always know how to distinguish between a namespace and a class name with the same name.

Change this:

```
using Engine.Configuration;
```

To a [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

```
using Configuration = Engine.Configuration.Configuration;
```

**Explenation:**

Let's say you are working directly under the root namespace, Engine, like so:

```
namespace Engine
{
}
```

Then you could get things in other namespaces like this:

```
namespace Engine
{
    Engine.Configuration.Configuration;

    // Or since you are in the root (Engine) you don't need to specify Engine:
    // You can always omit the root namespace if the namespace you're in has the same root.
    Configuration.Configuration;
}
```

Or by declaring a using for the namespace, but the compiler won't know if you mean the namespace or the class in the namespace:

```
using Engine.Configuration;

namespace Engine
{
    // This will still work.
    Engine.Configuration.Configuration;

    // This will break, do we mean "Engine.Configuration.Configuration" or "Engine.Configuration"?
    Configuration;
}
```

So it's a good practice to never have the same name for a class as the namespace it lives in. Maybe change the namespace to Engine.Configuration**s**.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
using A = Engine.Configuration;
```

then

```
x = A.Configuration.i;
```

or just use

```
x = global::Engine.Configuration.Configuration.i
```